# What are the different phases in creating the API life cycle in api Connect?

Tags: api, apiconnect

There is three Types like **Enforced,Test,CORS**. What would happen if we disabled them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifecycle states (phases) are:

- Identified (have identified that there is a need for an api that
  provides a specific capability)
- Specified (have started to flesh out
  what the API externals will look like)
- Realized (there is an actual backend to the API and can invoke and use it)

The other three options are related but aren't really "lifecycle states".

Enforced == whether the API will be managed by API Connect - is it deployed to the gateway? Disable this and the API will not be deployed out to the gateway, no analytics will be tracked on its usage, there will be no subscription management, etc... Basically turning this off means you need to have the actual API backend in the swagger document and have purely loaded it into APIC for socialisation / documentation purposes. It will not be managed by APIC.

Testable == do you want to allow users to test this API from the portal test tool ?

CORS == Do you want to enable Cross-Origin Resource Scripting support (this is required to invoke the API from any AJAX application anywhere - including the test tools in both API Manager and the portal)

If you have testable == true then you either need cors == true or you have to implement all the OPTIONS requests in your API manually. The test tool won't work otherwise.